# Search Function in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, search

I have to develop a search function in javascript such that it will display a message/pop-up window when users does not select an option in dropdownlist. I am using usercontrols in my project. so the dropdownlist's are in .ascx file and my search function will be in .aspx file. Here is the code which I am using:

```
function Search() 
    {
        var src_status = createObj("bodyuc_drp_Status").value;
        var src_program = createObj("bodyuc_drp_program").value;

        if(document.getElementById(src_program).value == 0 && document.getElementById(src_client).value == 0)
         {
            alert("Please select atleast one client or program")
            return false;
         }
        else {
            createObj("hdn_search").value = "Search";
            return true;
        }
    }
```

the value '0' in the if condition is the index of '--select one--' option in the dropdownlist. The above alert message should be displayed when the index is 0 otherwise the user should get the data based on his selection.

This code gives me alert message even if the users select a value other than the 'select one' option. Can anyone tell my why?

really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` property of the `select` element is the same as the `value` property for the selected `option` element, not its index. To get the index, use the `selectedIndex` property:

```
if(document.getElementById(src_program).selectedIndex == 0 && document.getElementById(src_client).selectedIndex == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the replly. Really appreciate it.